# How to know that the device is galaxy note (or any other specific handset model)

Tags: android, galaxy, imei

I am creating an app that uses SPen sdk . the sdk is only Galaxy Note compatible . I want to know at runtime if the phone my app is running on is Galaxy Note , if so I want to make use of SPen SDK classes , else i want to use Simple Canvas . **Is there any way of making sure that the phone is Galaxy Note .**

Thank You

Comment: You may be able to use device filters in the Play store to restrict the distribution of your app to specific models such as Galaxy Note.

Comment: I want the app to be compaitable with every device (not just galaxy note) i ll try to use normal canvas for other device and spen sdk for galaxy note alone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The S Pen SDK has a method:

SDrawLibrary.isSupportedModel()

It should return true if it's a supported device.

Comment: if i want to run the app on sdk versions lower than 10 then first I should check the android SDK version ,if it is lower than 10 i should simply use normal Canvas , if it is 10 or above then i should check by using the method mentioned above . This is correct right?

Comment: Depends on your target and min SDK. You may want to read up on Backward Compatibility. http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html

Comment: it's very poor method because all Samsung device gives `true`. maybe it is implemented something like `Build.Manufacturer.equal("samsung")`. (my assumption)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should avoid checking to see specifically if the device is a Galaxy Note.  Odds are there are other Samsung devices on the way with pen support that your app could probably support just fine.

Probably better would be to check to see 1) if the device has a stylus, and 2) is made by Samsung.  Only if both of these are true would you then use Samsung's SDK calls.

Dianne Hackborn of Google discusses how to check for 1) in this thread:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2Lckyn8-B8M/EGo00XPhXewJ

As for how to determine if the device is made by Samsung, you can check the BUILD value like this:

```
/**
 * Returns TRUE if the current device is built by Samsung.
 * 
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isSamsung() {
    return ( "samsung".equalsIgnoreCase(Build.MANUFACTURER)  );
}
```

Other people would advise that you should stay away from Samsung's SDK entirely, and develop your app using the pen event support already in ICS.  This would open your app to supporting active stylus devices from other manufacturers such as HTC, ASUS and Lenovo.

Comment: Is there any SDK that is every stylus(even a toothpick) compaitable and is used for drawing on screen , and has functions for customising the way things are drawn , I mean is similar to SPen SDK,but meant for every stylus

Comment: Ice Cream Sandwich has support for devices with dedicated stylus, such as the Galaxy Note and HTC Flyer.  You use the InputDevice class to determine the device ID of the stylus.  Then, when your view is passed a MotionEvent in the view's onTouchEvent() method, you can use MotionEvent#getDeviceId() to figure out which device created it.  An event created by the stylus will have additional pen-specific data such as pressure.